# Should I use http or ftp links in apt sources.list

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management

Should I use `http` or `ftp` links in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

What I mean is is using something like

```
deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib. non-free
deb-src ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib. non-free
```

better or worse than using

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib. non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib. non-free
```

?

I guess as `apt` uses `wget` to fetch things, this is same as asking if `wget` is faster on `ftp`.

Comment: No, apt does not use `wget`. It uses its own internal method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not going to save much time using one over the other, but if efficiency is what you care about, use HTTP.   An FTP client has to send a username and password and receive acknowledgments for those, and then issue several commands to set up the file transfer and receive acks for those, too.  All this back and forth magnifies the effect of network latency; with 100-200ms ping times to the server you could waste a second setting up the transfer.  With HTTP, the client opens the connection, sends one command and the file transfer starts immediately.

Comment: Always use HTTP. We need to discourage the use of FTP so that it can be made obsolete sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, personnally I would go with FTP (stands for File Transfer Protocol) whose primary goal is... file transfer. But if you want to be sure, like empirically sure, there are a few utilities that might do the job (i.e. test, compare and select the fastest ones) for you. Those I know of are netselect-apt (same package name) and apt-spy. You don't have to give them a server list as they will download it from Debian main server.